# Luminosity ratio accessibility issue of reCAPTCHA v3

Tags: accessibility, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

When using the google reCAPTCHA v3 under private mode and the verification challenge was expired, the font color(#F00) and the background color(#F4F4F4) didn't match the luminosity ratio standard of CCA(Color contrast analyser) tool.

Wondering if there is an open case or any possible ways we could customize the font color?

Many thanks[image]

Tried to change the CSS styling with no luck.
It is being added to sites as an iframe element and targeting iframes with CSS is not possible. So, unfortunately, even though we can modify the style via browser inspector, that cannot be done in the backend of the site, and the color was set by the component itself.